# D'où vient le terme « Sèche » pour une cigarette?

Tags: étymologie, argot

D'où vient le mot « Sèche » utilisé pour parler d'une cigarette, par exemple dans la phrase « Je vais me griller une sèche ».

---

Whence comes the word “Sèche”, which is used to refer to a cigarette, for example in the sentence: “Je vais me griller une sèche”?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sur *[Les expressions françaises décortiquées](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/fumer-une-seche-une-clope.php)*, on trouve une étymologie qui me semble plausible même si je n'ai pas de référence plus conventionelle à proposer :

> Si l'étymologie n'est pas certaine, Rigaud, dans son *Dictionnaire du jargon parisien* publié en 1878, indique que la sèche a désigné la cigarette de manufacture, ce beau tuyau rempli de tabac parfaitement cylindrique fabriqué en usine.
>
> Mais pourquoi ? Eh bien ce serait simplement par opposition à l'informe cigarette roulée dont le papier, collé à la salive, était en partie humide.

Comment: C'est vrai également que le tabac en vrac est plus "humide" que le tabac des cigarettes en paquet...

Answer (score 0):

Manifestement, l'usage de [*sèche*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A8che/substantif/2) pour cigarette était déjà recensé en 1874 et dériverait du mot *sec*. Pourquoi et comment, par contre, mystère et boule de gomme.